# How to make a type under a PK unique without the SK being unique?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB and use the Single Table Design.

I have a Type Character that must only be eable to join one Room at a time.

My access patterns are:

- Get the Room the Character is in (by characterId)
- Get all the Characters of a Room (by roomId)

My solution was to use the Word "Room" as SK making it therefore unique and adding the roomId as attribute. But I would rather use the roomId as SK so I could use the GSI 1 (pk sk swap) to query it more easly and I would not have to create 3 Items, only 2.

Is there a way to use roomId as SK but still prevent there ever being two? It's fine if the solution would be in code only. It does not have to be impossible by design like my solution. But it should still be impossible to create two types when two requests come in at the same time. Or is creating 3 Items the correct approach?

Table Aggregate View
[image: Table Aggregate View]

GSI 1 (pk sk swap) Aggregate View
[image: GSI 1 Aggregate View]

Comment: Are Character#s and Room#s globally unique?  Can a character be in two rooms at the same time?

Comment: @AlexChadyuk Character#s and Room#s are unique, because their ID is use in the PK aswell in the SK. A character should not be eable to be in two rooms at the same time!